# Vim: Saving on FocusLost and executing auto command

Tags: vim, autocmd

I've setup my vim editor (I use MacVim) to save files automatically when the focus is lost:

```
autocmd FocusLost * silent! wall
```

I also automatically strip trailing whitespace from python files using this auto command:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.py :%s/\s\+$//e
```

This auto command works perfectly when I save the file manually (either by typing <kbd>:w</kbd> or by pressing <kbd>⌘s</kbd>) but it is not executed (i.e. the whitespace is not stripped) when I switch to another application and the buffer is automatically written.

How can I modify these auto commands to make them work together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your FocusLost autocommand to:

```
autocmd FocusLost * nested silent! wall
```

See `:h autocmd-nested` for details.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this in a graphic Vim, but you can try some options:

- Join some events in the same autocommand `autocmd BufWritePre,FocusLost *.py ...`
- Execute an autocommand from an event, something like:
  `autocmd BufWritePre *.py :execute "%s/\s\+$//e" | doautocmd FocusLost %`

Comment: Thanks... could have thought of it myself! ;-) I used the "multiple events joined" method.

Comment: Have you any thoughts why it does not work straight with my original setup?

Comment: @GaretJax: Sorry, I can't help with that question. Seems like autocommands cannot be chained, but no idea about the reason.