# How to get rid of Error detected while processing FocusLost Auto commands in VIM

Tags: macvim

I'm trying to get rid of

```
Error detected while processing FocusLost Auto commands for "*":
E141: No file name for buffer 1
```

I checked out:
[Vim: Saving on FocusLost and executing auto command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574387/vim-saving-on-focuslost-and-executing-auto-command)

and: [How can I make Vim autosave files when it loses focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637575/how-can-i-make-vim-autosave-files-when-it-loses-focus)

but adding `autocmd FocusLost * nested silent! wall` to the end of my `.vimrc` didn't help

Any ideas?

I'm using MacVim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this just because you haven't provided a filename yet?

It might not happen if you run

```
:w myfilename
```

straight away. When I tested the above line in my .vimrc (on Debian) it worked just fine with gVim. But only after I'd provided a filename.

I don't get the error you're getting when I don't provide a filename though.

Comment: I see this as a workaround, I wish it was able to just let it be as it is when there is no filename, so only autosaving items that do have a filename.